# How do I replace characters before a specific character?

Tags: c

Values:

```
hw:2,0
```

I want to replace the string before **:** with **dsnoop**

Result:

```
dsnoop:2,0
```

Or reverse `dsnoop` with `hw`

I have this function to find useless devices

```
bool useless_device(char *device) {
    char *example[] = { "dsnoop", "dmix", "hw" };
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(example); i++) {
        int l = strlen(example[i]);
        if (device && strncmp (device, example[i], l) == 0 && (!device[l] || device[l] == ':'))
            return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

I am trying to make a function that will take as input a string and replace `hw` with the `dsnoop` (or vice versa).
So, for `"hw:x,y"`, should return `"dsnoop:x,y"` (or vice versa).

```
char *useless_device(const char *device) {
    int i, j;
    char *useless[] = { "dsnoop", "hw" };
    char *result = NULL;

    char *dev;
    dev = g_strdup(device);
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(useless); i++) {
        char *buf;
        int len = strlen(useless[i]);
        if (strncmp (dev, useless[i], len) == 0 && (!dev[len] || dev[len] == ':')) {
            buf = g_strdup (&dev[len]);
            j = (i + 1) % ARRAY_SIZE(useless);
            result = g_strconcat(useless[j], buf, NULL);
            g_free(buf);
        }
    }
    g_free(dev);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you read about the [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), the [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) functions, they are all you need (plus a temporary buffer).

Comment: Looks like an ALSA thing. Not sure, but aren't there already functions to differentiate devices, instead of parsing character sequences?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your function fails is you do not break from the loop once you find a match.  So the replacement can take place twice, effectively cancelling itself.

You can fix and simplify the function this way:

```
char *useless_device(const char *device) {
    int i;
    const char *useless[] = { "dsnoop", "hw" };

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(useless); i++) {
        int len = strlen(useless[i]);
        if (strncmp(device, useless[i], len) == 0 &&
            (!device[len] || device[len] == ':')) {
            return g_strconcat(useless[i ^ 1], device + len, NULL);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This would also work with an array with multiple pairs of names to swap.